# Updating GPU's on google cloud platform with CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gpu, google-compute-engine

In Deep learning training processb on the Google cloud platfotm, I wish to add or remove GPU's from virtual machines from time to time.
Doing it with the UI is slow and cumbersome.
Is this possible with their CLI? (gcloud...)
I woold expect it be under `gcloud compute instances update ...` but its not.
On machine creation its possibel with the `gcloud compute instances create --accelerator` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the number of GPU's in already created GCP VM with `gcloud`.

However [you can do it via API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#add-gpu-to-instance):

```
{
 "guestAccelerators": [
  {
    "acceleratorCount": accelerator-count,
    "acceleratorType": "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-id/zones/zone/acceleratorTypes/accelerator-type"
  }
 ]
}
```

You can also requet such a feature in `gcloud` on [Google IssueTracker and file a new feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=187143&template=1163129).